# Get field from subcollection's parent document

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am creating a message application with Firestore

At the moment i have created a function that gets triggered when a user writes a message in a `messageRoom`. Each `messageRoom` document has a subcollection called `messages` which contains the messages of the room. The `messageRoom` document itself contains data related to the `messageRoom` itself e.g. users who are part of the `messageRoom`. The `messageRoom` contains a field called `members` which holds info about the user who are a part of the `messageRoom`

I want to get access to the data in the `messageRoom` document and not the `messages` subcollection. At the moment the following code does not work. An error tells me that the `members` field is undefined. What have i done wrong?

```
exports.sendNotification = functions
  .firestore
  .document('messageRooms/{messageRoomId}/messages/{messageId}')
  .onCreate(  
  async (snapshot) => {
    /*
    Does something with the documents in the subcollection
    */

    //Get the DocumentReference of the parent doc
    const parentDocId = snapshot.ref.parent.id;

    admin.firestore().collection('messageRooms').doc(parentDocId).get('members').get().then(doc => {
      if (doc.exists) {
         console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
      } else {
          // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
          console.log("No such document!");
      }
      return; //return added to prevent crash
   }).catch(error => {
      console.log("Error getting document:", error);
   });
  }
);
```

Comment: You can't get a specific field from a document in a single query.  You have to `get()` then entire document, the find the field in the snapshot it returns.  I suggest reviewing the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problems is here:

```
//Get the DocumentReference of the parent doc
    const parentDocId = snapshot.ref.parent.id;
```

snapshot is `DocumentSnapshot`, so ref property give us `DocumentReference`. Property `parent` of document reference is `CollectionReference` ([Google Doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#parent)). So you have to find not parent but "grandparent" :) I may say. Maybe try:

```
const parentDocId = snapshot.ref.parent.parent.id;
```

However I would not use `.id` property here just to get reference in `.doc` in next line. `parent` property already provides reference ([doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#parent)). I don't think that argument in `get` is changing anything, so I would use `.data().messages` to get to the field. In the end I would use:

```
const parentDocRef = snapshot.ref.parent.parent;

    parentDocRef.get().then(doc => { console.log(doc.data().members)})
```

I hope it will help!

Comment: When i try your last suggestion I get 2 errors:
Expected catch() or return
Each then() should return a value or throw
I've encountered this before but never really understood it

Comment: This must be matter of environment, I don't have such errors working on linux and node v10.14